# Threaded Buffer crashes

Tags: python, multithreading, buffer

I tried to implement a 5 element buffer through threading and a list.

```
import threading

class Buffer1 :
    
    def __init__(self,size) :
        self.empty = True
        self.content = None
        self.lock = threading.Condition()
        self.list = []
        
        
    def take(self) :
        with self.lock :
            while not self.list :
                self.lock.wait()  
            help = self.list[len(self.list)-1]
            del self.list[len(self.list)-1]
            self.lock.notify_all() 
                                   
            
            return help
        
    def put(self,v) :
        with self.lock :
            while len(self.list) >4:
                self.lock.wait()
            #self.content = v
            self.list.append(v)
            self.empty = False
            self.lock.notify_all()
            
    def show_list(self):
        return self.list
            
a = Buffer1(5)
a.put(7)
```

Theoretically it works, but when you exceed the limitations of the buffer, either by buffering 6 values or by trying to „take()“ when there is no value buffered, the IDE becomes unresponsive. How could I go about fixing this?

Comment: Have two separate threads that put in and take from the buffer?

Answer (score 2):

You are using only one thread to add elements in the buffer, so the list contains 5 items, and your main thread is waiting indefinitely on `self.lock.wait()`. You can **use another thread** that would take some elements in parallel and then it will notify the producer thread.

For example, creation of a consumer thread that takes 5 items:

```
def consume(buffer):
    import time
    for i in range(5):
        print(threading.current_thread(), "consume", buffer.take())
        time.sleep(2)
    print(threading.current_thread(), "Bye")


buffer = Buffer1(5)
t = threading.Thread(target=consume, args=(buffer,), name="consumer")
t.start()

buffer.put(1)
buffer.put(2)
buffer.put(3)
buffer.put(4)
buffer.put(5)
buffer.put(6)
print(buffer.show_list())
```

Comment: But wouldn't this force me to fill the buffer completely every time because of the range function? So I wouldn’t be able to, say put 3 elements only. Or do I miss something here?

Answer (score 1):

> ... the IDE becomes unresponsive. How could I go about fixing this?

You only showed adding to the buffer from the main thread and nothing ever takes anything out.

If the buffer gets filled up or becomes empty the next put/take will cause its Condition (`lock`) [to wait](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#condition-objects) until something notifies it to continue. I didn't see any of that signaling in your example.

The buffer is a shared resource. The buffer and the threads that use it need to have good control so that everyone can stay out of everyone else's way and enough logic to keep from getting stuck somewhere.

Presumably you need a thread that puts stuff into the buffer and a thread that takes stuff out of the buffer - both having ample signaling to notify everyone when they are done messing with the buffer.

---

- Set up logging so that the program execution could be *traced* with log messages.
- Buffer1 changes:

  - Changed the list to a collections.deque to simplify things a bit.
  - Added properties for empty and full
  - Added an Event attribute to stop putting/taking when the process gets *shut down*.
  - Added a timeout while waiting to put/take to forestall any timing issues when the threads are *shut down*
  - Added notifications for empty and full conditions.
- Made two threads: one to add to the buffer and one to take from the buffer.

  - Each will add/take while its Event is not set.
  - In each iteration a random number of items are taken or added.
  - When taking/putting the buffer's Condition is acquired and all *Waiter's* are notified when complete.
- In the main thread:

  - An Event is created - for signaling the thread to quit
  - A Timer is created to limit thread execution time - when it times out its *callback* function sets the Event and uses the buffer's Condition (`lock`) to notify anyone that is waiting and free them up.
  - The threads are created, started, and joined.

---

```
import threading
import collections
import random
import string
import time
import logging
import sys

# logging setup
root = logging.getLogger()
root.setLevel(logging.INFO)

formatter = logging.Formatter(fmt='%(asctime)s.%(msecs)03d %(message)s',
                              datefmt='%S')

class WarningFilter(logging.Filter):
    def filter(self, record):
        return record.levelno == logging.WARNING

class InfoFilter(logging.Filter):
    def filter(self, record):
        return record.levelno == logging.INFO

handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
handler.setFormatter(formatter)
handler.addFilter(InfoFilter())
root.addHandler(handler)

handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stderr)
handler.setLevel(logging.WARNING)
handler.setFormatter(formatter)
handler.addFilter(WarningFilter())
root.addHandler(handler)
# logging setup end

class Buffer1:
    '''FILO buffer.
    '''
    def __init__(self,size,evt) :
        self.content = None
        self.size = size
        self.evt = evt
        self.lock = threading.Condition()
        self.list = collections.deque()

    @property
    def full(self):
        return len(self.list) >= self.size
    @property
    def empty(self):
        return bool(self.list)
    
    def take(self) :
        with self.lock :
            while not self.empty:
                root.warning('buffer empty waiting to take')
                self.lock.wait(timeout=5)
                if self.evt.is_set():
                    help = None
                    break
            else:
                help = self.list.pop()
            self.lock.notify_all() 
        return help
        
    def put(self,v):
        success = False
        with self.lock :
            while self.full:
                root.warning('buffer full waiting to put')
                self.lock.wait(timeout=5)
                if self.evt.is_set():
                    break
            else:
                self.list.append(v)
                success = True
            self.lock.notify_all()
        return success

    def show_list(self):
        return self.list

class Prod(threading.Thread):
    '''Puts stuff onto buffer, quits on Event.

       Contrived toy - periodically puts random n items in buffer. 
    '''
    def __init__(self,buffer,evt):
        super().__init__(name='producer')
        self.buffer = buffer
        self.evt = evt
    def run(self):
        n = 0
        while not self.evt.is_set():
            howmany = random.randint(1,9)
            payload = random.sample(string.ascii_letters,howmany)
            payload = collections.deque(payload)
            root.info(f'{self.name} putting {howmany}')
            with self.buffer.lock:
                while payload and (not self.evt.is_set()):
                    c = payload.popleft()
                    root.info(f'{self.name} -----> {c}')
                    if not self.buffer.put(c):
                        root.warning(f'{self.name} last put failed')
                self.buffer.lock.notify_all()
            time.sleep(.04)
            n += 1
        root.info(f'{self.name} dying n={n}')
        with self.buffer.lock:
            self.buffer.lock.notify_all()
        root.info(f'{self.name} is done')
        
class Cons(threading.Thread):
    '''Takes stuff off of buffer, quits on Event set.

       Contrived toy - periodically takes random n items from buffer. 
    '''
    def __init__(self,buffer,evt):
        super().__init__(name='consumer')
        self.buffer = buffer
        self.evt = evt
    def run(self):
        n = 0
        while not self.evt.is_set():
            howmany = random.randint(1,9)
            root.info(f'{self.name} taking {howmany}')
            with self.buffer.lock:
                while (howmany > 0) and (not self.evt.is_set()):
                    c = self.buffer.take()
                    root.info(f'{self.name} <----- {c}')
                    howmany -= 1
                self.buffer.lock.notify_all()
            time.sleep(.04)
            n += 1
        root.info(f'{self.name} dying n={n}')
        with self.buffer.lock:
            self.buffer.lock.notify_all()
        root.info(f'{self.name} is done')

if __name__ == '__main__':

    # use an Event to shut down the whole process
    evt = threading.Event()
    buffer = Buffer1(5,evt)

    def kill(evt=evt,buffer=buffer):
        root.warning('killing everything')
        evt.set()
        with buffer.lock:
            buffer.lock.notify_all()

    # don't let this toy example run forever
    t = threading.Timer(5,kill)
    t.start()

    p1 = Prod(buffer,evt)
    c1 = Cons(buffer,evt)
    c1.start()
    p1.start()
    p1.join()
    c1.join()
    print('exit')
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another take using [asyncio](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html) instead of threads to exercise your buffer.

```
import asyncio
import collections
import random
import string
import time
import logging
import sys



# logging setup
root = logging.getLogger()
root.setLevel(logging.INFO)

formatter = logging.Formatter(fmt='%(asctime)s.%(msecs)03d %(message)s',
                              datefmt='%S')

class WarningFilter(logging.Filter):
    def filter(self, record):
        return record.levelno == logging.WARNING

class InfoFilter(logging.Filter):
    def filter(self, record):
        return record.levelno == logging.INFO

handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
handler.setFormatter(formatter)
handler.addFilter(InfoFilter())
root.addHandler(handler)

handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stderr)
handler.setLevel(logging.WARNING)
handler.setFormatter(formatter)
handler.addFilter(WarningFilter())
root.addHandler(handler)

class Buffer:
    '''FILO buffer.
    '''
    def __init__(self,size,evt) :
        self.content = None
        self.size = size
        self.stop_evt = evt
        self.lock = asyncio.Condition()
        self.list = collections.deque()

    def full(self):
        return len(self.list) >= self.size
    def not_full(self):
        return len(self.list) < self.size
    def empty(self):
        return not bool(self.list)
    def not_empty(self):
        return bool(self.list)
    
    async def take(self) :
        async with self.lock:
            #root.info(f'take:lock acquired - wait for not empty')
            while self.empty():
                waiters = [thing for thing in self.lock._waiters]
                #root.warning(f'take:{waiters} waiting')
                await self.lock.wait()
                if self.stop_evt.is_set():    # shutting down
                    val = None
            else:
                #root.info('take: not empty')
                val = self.list.pop()
            self.lock.notify_all() 
        return val
        
    async def put(self,v):
        success = False
        async with self.lock:
            #root.info(f'put:lock acquired - wait for not full')
            while self.full():
                waiters = [thing for thing in self.lock._waiters]
                #root.warning(f'put:{waiters} waiting')
                await self.lock.wait()
                if self.stop_evt.is_set():    # shutting down
                    break
            else:
                #root.info('put: not full')
                self.list.append(v)
                success = True
            self.lock.notify_all()
        return success

    def show_list(self):
        return self.list
    
async def random_stuff():
    howmany = random.randint(1,9)
    payload = random.sample(string.ascii_letters,howmany)
    return collections.deque(payload)
    
async def produce(buffer,stop_evt,name):
    puts = []
    try:
        while True:
            payload = await random_stuff()
            root.warning(f'producer{name} putting {len(payload)}')
            while payload:
                c = payload.popleft()
                root.info(f'producer{name} -----> {c}')
                success = await buffer.put(c)
                if not success:
                    root.warning(f'producer{name} failed to put {c}')
                else:
                    puts.append(c)
            await asyncio.sleep(.03)
    except asyncio.CancelledError as e:
        root.warning('producer canceled')
    root.info(f'producer{name} dying n={len(puts)}')
    root.info(f'producer{name} is done')
    return puts

   
async def consume(buffer, stop_evt, name):
    '''Takes stuff off of buffer, quits on Event set.

       Contrived toy - periodically takes random n items from buffer. 
    '''
    takes = []
    try:
        while True:
            howmany = random.randint(1,9)
            msg = f'consumer{name} taking {howmany}'
            root.warning(f'{msg:>38}')
            while howmany > 0:
                c = await buffer.take()
                takes.append(c)
                msg = f'consumer{name} <----- {c}'
                root.info(f'{msg:>38}')
                howmany -= 1
            await asyncio.sleep(.02)
    except asyncio.CancelledError as e:
        root.warning('consumer canceled')
    root.info(f'consumer{name} dying n={len(takes)}')
    root.info(f'consumer{name} is done')
    return takes

async def timer(n,buffer,evt, tasks):
    root.warning('timer started')
    await asyncio.sleep(n)
    evt.set()
    root.warning('timed out - event set')
    root.warning('canceling tasks')
    for task in tasks:
        task.cancel()
        

async def main():

    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
    loop.set_debug(True)

    # use an Event to shut down the whole process
    evt = asyncio.Event()
    buffer = Buffer(5,evt)
    
    put_task = asyncio.create_task(produce(buffer,evt,1))
    take_task = asyncio.create_task(consume(buffer,evt,1))
    timer_task = asyncio.create_task(timer(5,buffer,evt,[put_task,take_task]))
    root.info('tasks created')
    await timer_task
    puts = await put_task
    takes = await take_task
    print('exit')
    return puts,takes,buffer.list

if __name__ == '__main__':

    puts,takes,remains = asyncio.run(main())
    puts = collections.Counter(puts)
    takes = collections.Counter(takes)
    remains = collections.Counter(remains)
    #print(remains == (puts-takes))
```